# How to get the assigned activity for HOME key long press, programmatically in android?

Tags: android, android-homebutton

In some android versions HOME key long press results in showing up recent app list. but in some, its assigned for "Google now" search.
So from my application programmatically, how can I get the activity name that's being mapped/assigned to HOME key long press? Is it possible?

Comment: i bet you should play with intent-filters related to the HOME category ... take a look at the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836869/android-how-to-control-the-home-button?rq=1 and int http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862629/overriding-home-button-for-a-car-home-replacement-app?lq=1 for inspiration!

Comment: I guess you can not get that for sure, since manufacturers change the home long press in different ways.